# How to take value before first value of groupy group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

After applying groupby on my data I want to save some values. I have two columns in dataframe, x1 and x2. apply groupby function by x2 column and get Value from x1 before the first value of group.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'x1':[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,7],x2:[1,3,3,3,2,2,2,2]})
   x1  x2
0   3   1
1   4   3
2   5   3
3   6   3
4   7   2
5   8   2
6   9   2
7   2   2
8   7   2

desired output:

df_out=pd.DataFrame({'x1_value':[3,6]})
      x1_value
0         3
1         6
```

Comment: `df.x1.shift().groupby(df.x2).nth(0).dropna()`

Comment: Or maybe something like `np.unique(df.x2, return_index=True)[1] - 1`?

Comment: df.groupby(x2).agg({'x1':['first']})  i am using this to get first value of group , there is any same way to get value before the first value ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using [`nth`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-nth) from pandas 0.25:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'x1':[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,7],'x2':[1,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2]})

df.groupby('x2', sort=False).nth(-1)[:-1]
```

Output:

```
    x1
x2    
1    3
3    6
```

Details:

- Group by x2 with sort = False
- use `nth` to get the last value of each group
- Slice to eliminate last value in last group

Answer (score 1):

*Setup*

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'x1':[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,7],'x2':[1,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2]})

x1  x2
0   3   1
1   4   3
2   5   3
3   6   3
4   7   2
5   8   2
6   9   2
7   2   2
8   7   2
```

You can groupby on x2 shifted by 1 position and take the first x1.

```
df.groupby(df.x2.shift(-1),sort=False).x1.first()

x2
3    3.0
2    6.0
Name: x1_new, dtype: float64
```

Another more complicated solution by building a temp column:

```
(
    df.assign(x1_new=df.x1.shift())
    .groupby('x2',sort=False)
    .x1_new
    .first()
    .dropna()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case

```
df.groupby('x2').tail(1).iloc[:-1]
   x1  x2
0   3   1
3   6   3
```